# How to repair porcelain tile surface level chip in wet area?

Tags: tile, porcelain

I installed `12" x 24"` tile in my shower, and when removing the lippage control spacers for large format tiles, the spacers had a tendency to apply pressure against the tile edge's front corner and chip the pattern.

I have several of these surface level blemishes to deal with now. They are not deep at all, perhaps `0.5mm`. Unfortunately, I have too many separate tiles damaged for removal and replacement to be a good option.

What are options for *repairing* this kind of damage? I'd be satisfied with a close color match, but mainly looking for something that will stand up to being in a shower (lots of water and cleanings in future).

[image]

Comment: This is just bizarre. Spacers are usually soft plastic (almost _rubber_), and any tile worth a hoot should withstand that. What went wrong? (And why didn't you change tactics after the first incident?!) I'm curious.

Comment: I was as baffles as you given the materials. I used the LASH system. Indeed, plastic spacers. The instructions say, knock it apart with a rubber mallet swing or a kick of the shoe. Since they're on the wall, I chose the mallet.

The first chip was small and I thought to myself. Just coincidence... the second, I was like, hmm, pattern? The third, I was convinced. I decided to switch tactics to plyers and rip the spacer out straight, so it doesn't make contact with the tiles.

Again, I was in disbelief it could happen beyond the first instance. I'm a fool since it got me thrice. =D

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I've had success with fixing minor chips like this. The first one is get some appliance touchup paint from your home store or tile store. It's a small bottle and comes with a cap brush and is available in many colors. You can mix them together to try and match your tile color. The other way is to get some matching  acrylic nail polish which is available in thousands of colors and drop on a dab so it spreads and connects to all the edges of the chips. Once either one hardens, it's almost harder than the original surface as far as chipping.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider getting a (white) colored epoxy resin and building up the chips to be flush with the tile.  Since it's a wet area, wet sanding it smooth shouldn't be a problem!